# How do I get the position of the Turtlebot at current time and check if that pose is exactly same to the pose in the plan provided by the planner?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using the navigation stack to generate a global plan. Once the plan is generated, I can see the Turtlebot navigating in Gazebo. I need to know how to check the Turtlebot's current position in the map and if it is following the same plan generated by the planner. How can I do this by code.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241952/how-do-i-get-the-position-of-the-turtlebot-at-current-time-and-check-if-that-pose-is-exactly-same-to-the-pose-in-the-plan-provided-by-the-planner?/) by [Karthikeyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/27730/karthikeyan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-08-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Generally, the navigation stack get the robot position from `odometry`, which comes from your robot encoders. In the simulation environments(e.g. Gazebo), the `odometry` is always right, and your robot position is always right, so your robot is always following the plan.

But in the real world, the `odometry` is only right for a short time, and then both the position and orientation will drift. So the real robot will not follow the plan generated by the planner. To know if your robot is following the plan, you need additional position methods, such as `GPS` and `amcl`, which can tell you the robot's position relative to the 'world'. With these info, you can know if the robot is following the plan.

---

Originally posted by [Shay](https://answers.ros.org/users/27777/shay/) with karma: 763 on 2016-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0